# Checking my CFG to CNF answer

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I attempted to transform the given CFG into CNF.

$$S → ASA|A$$

$$A→aa|ε$$

Here are my steps:

1. $$S→X$$

   $$X→XA|AX|A$$

   $$A→aa$$
2. $$S→X$$

   $$X→XA|AX|YY$$

   $$A→YY$$

   $$Y→a$$
3. $$S→XA|AX|YY$$

   $$X→XA|AX|YY$$

   $$A→YY$$

   $$Y→a$$

Is that one a correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps in the following order

1)Remove ε production

```
 S→ASA|AS|SA|A( You can ignore S->S )
 A→aa
```

2)Remove Unit Production(Non Terminal->Single Non Terminal)

Here we have unit production S->A

```
S→ASA|AS|SA|aa
A->aa
```

3)Remove Long Production(restructure the grammar such that R.H.S. have either 2 Non Terminal or single Terminal symbol)

S→AX|AS|SA|YY

X→SA

A→YY

Y→a